# Using browser location inside of SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have a webpage that uses location data from the browser that I want to open up inside an ios application.

If I open this page up inside a UIWebview I will see the page ask for location and after I respond the page finishes loading.

However, when I try to open this page up inside of a SFSafariViewController I do not get prompted for location which prevents the page from loading. I definitely want to use SFSafariViewController but I first need to fix this problem.

I've been unable to find any information about using location with SFSafariViewController. Does anyone know how to get this working?